# Behaviour of negative array index in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm newbie in C#. I know C and C++ language. Currently I have a C# related project. So, I just want to know basic concept about C#.

In C#, If I give negative array index, then What happens? Is it Undefined behaviour?

Like :

```
int [] arr = {1,2,3};
Console.WriteLine("{0}", arr[-1]);
```

Comment: Why not simply try it out? I think we can expect a 14k-user to at least know what kind of question you may ask on Stack and *how* to do so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your program will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception any time the index is out of the range of valid indexes for that array.

Had you taken a second to try it, you would've seen that for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
int [] arr = {1,2,3};
```

Compiler will transform the above syntactic sugar internally as

```
 int [] arr = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

so arr length is calculated as 3 by the compiler automatically.

Compiler will not allow you define array of unknown size.

```
int[] arr=new int[];//compiler error,array creation must have size.
```

So below statement

```
Console.WriteLine(arr[-1]);
```

will throw *an unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'*.

Comment: arr={1,2,3} internally will be transformed as int[].And also why -1 is not allowed because array index starts from 0 and thats because it uses pointers internally and below  0 is junk value and hence compiler warns from giving invalid indices.And also I am tying in mobile didnt see your answer before.

Answer (score 0):

If you access an array out of its index range, you'll get an System.IndexOutOfRangeException.
This exception you'll get for any negative index or any index larger or equal array.Length.